# Javascript/jQuery XSS potential reading from query strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, html-entities

My javascript reads data from a query string and puts that data into a text box using `jQuery.val()`.

This works fine but I am wondering is this safe from XSS attacks?

Say the query string looked like...

`site.com?q="javascript:alert(document.cookie)`

Which would effectively do:

`jQuery.val('"javascript:alert(document.cookie)')`

From what I have tested in IE8 / firefox this sets the input value as seen and doesn't do the actual injection.

If I run this function over the string first:

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    return str.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/'/g, '&#039;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Then you literally see `&quot;javascript:alert(document.cookie)` in the input value which is not what I want.

Using jQuery 1.5.2 I guess my question is does `jQuery.val()` handle the HTML entities for you and is therefore considered safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the following:

```
jQuery("#SomeTextbox").val("new value for SomeTextbox")
```

the jQuery code for the `val` function simply does this:

```
this.value = "new value for SomeTextbox";
```

where `this` is a reference to the `Text` object in the DOM that represents the textbox with id "SomeTextbox". The string `"new value for SomeTextbox"` is stored as the `value` property of that DOM object. It does not get transformed or sanitized in any way. But it doesn't get parsed/interpreted by the JavaScript engine either (e.g. as it would with `InnerHTML`). So regardless of what your argument to `val` is, it isn't going to "do" anything. It just changes the value of a string property of an object in the DOM. So, yes, it would be safe.

**EDIT:**

Here is some additional information that you may find helpful.

In general, putting something into a text box, no matter how malicious it may appear, and regardless of how it gets there is "safe" as long as it **stays** in the text box. But it matters a lot where it goes from there.

If the content of the textbox is subsequently rendered in a stream of parsed HTML, then it is no longer safe. A common scenario is to store the content of a textbox in a database, then retrieve it later and render it in a context where the browser parses is as HTML. If the re-display occurs in the context of a different user, it creates an opportunity for a malicious user to enter data into the textbox in order to gain access to another users private information at some future time.

Comment: @fire - After posting the answer above, I thought of something else that you might find helpful. Although you have already accepted my original answer, I decided to post the additional material anyway, because I think it may answer a deeper question that underlies the one that you asked.  Good luck keeping the hackers at bay!!